# Change marker position by Realtime lat & lang in Firebase database without added new one marker

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, google-maps-markers

My realtime Firebase database

[image]

I try to change position for many lat langs at some time like cars in uber, 
but when I change lat or lang or both this don't change the position of marker but its make anew marker. I want when lat for example is changed in realtime database the markers also changed based on the value of that lat

I try make condition

```
`if (marker != null) 
    setPosition 
 else "marker == null"` 
    add new marker
```

but the problem is I have >1 markers so that this solution is display me on the map one marker only because marker != null

```
public class Map extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
FirebaseDatabase database;
DatabaseReference myRef;
GoogleMap mMap;
MarkerOptions options;
Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
LatLng ll;
model save;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

  @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    myRef = database.getReference("user");

    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                Double lang = ds.child("lang").getValue(Double.class);
                Double lat = ds.child("lat").getValue(Double.class);
                save = new model(lat, lang);
                ll = new LatLng(save.getLat(), save.getLang());

                mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(options
                        .position(ll));

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

I expected the marker's position was changed when I change real time lat and lang in firebase, but the result is created another marker.

Comment: Please share the complete code of this class

Comment: one second i will copy it

Comment: @HemendraGangwar done

Comment: You want to track user's current position using a marker?

Comment: @Alex Mamo exactly that i want

Comment: @mohamedgaber , please let me know if you are Kotin familiar, show that i can share complete track code

Comment: @HemendraGangwar yea thats very kind of you <33

Comment: Will an answer that explains how to enable your current position using that blue dot helpful?

Comment: @Alex Mamo i already make that in my app <3 and make it setvalue in realtime database my problem with read this value without add new marker just change position you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following from my comments on other answers, here is what I've come up with based on your question.

This code will show multiple markers on the map, but only one marker for each ID under `/users` in the database. If the location for a particular ID changes, it's associated marker will be moved without affecting the other markers on the map.

**Warning:** The below code will update your map in real-time. You may which to cache the new marker locations and only update them once every 2-5 seconds or so depending on your how frequently your data changes.

Some quick notes before diving into the code:

- Each marker is linked to it's string ID in the database under a Map called `mNamedMarkers`.
- As `model` was not provided and seems irrelevant, I have omitted it from the code below.
- I'm not sure if you are coming from a Germanic background, but `lng` is short for Longitude, not "lang" in this context. I would also change your database entries to use `lng` rather than lang/long/longitude/etc (it saves space & eliminates confusion).
- In the code below, I've added `getMarkerOptions(key)`, this is so that you can add code to get different images, titles, and text for each marker based on it's ID. Currently it will produce the same data for each marker.
- I've added Javadoc mark-up for each function to summarize what each does.
- There are a couple of TODOs for further development.

Here is the code:

```
public class Map extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference userLocationsRef;
    GoogleMap mMap;

    Map<String, Marker> mNamedMarkers = new HashMap<String,Marker>();

    ChildEventListener markerUpdateListener = new ChildEventListener() {

            /**
             * Adds each existing/new location of a marker.
             *
             * Will silently update any existing markers as needed.
             * @param dataSnapshot  The new location data
             * @param previousChildName  The key of the previous child event
             */
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
                    String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                    Log.d(TAG, "Adding location for '" + key + "'");

                    Double lng = ds.child("lang").getValue(Double.class);
                    Double lat = ds.child("lat").getValue(Double.class);
                    LatLng location = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                    Marker marker = mNamedMarkers.get(key);

                    if (marker == null) {
                        MarkerOptions options = getMarkerOptions(key);
                        marker = mMap.addMarker(options.position(location));
                        mNamedMarkers.put(key, marker);
                    } else {
                        // This marker-already-exists section should never be called in this listener's normal use, but is here to handle edge cases quietly.
                        // TODO: Confirm if marker title/snippet needs updating.
                        marker.setPosition(location);
                    }
            }

            /**
             * Updates the location of a previously loaded marker.
             *
             * Will silently create any missing markers as needed.
             * @param dataSnapshot  The new location data
             * @param previousChildName  The key of the previous child event
             */
            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
                    String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                    Log.d(TAG, "Location for '" + key + "' was updated.");

                    Double lng = ds.child("lang").getValue(Double.class);
                    Double lat = ds.child("lat").getValue(Double.class);
                    LatLng location = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                    Marker marker = mNamedMarkers.get(key);

                    if (marker == null) {
                        // This null-handling section should never be called in this listener's normal use, but is here to handle edge cases quietly.
                        Log.d(TAG, "Expected existing marker for '" + key + "', but one was not found. Added now.");
                        MarkerOptions options = getMarkerOptions(key); // TODO: Read data from database for this marker (e.g. Name, Driver, Vehicle type)
                        marker = mMap.addMarker(options.position(location));
                        mNamedMarkers.put(key, marker);
                    } else {
                        // TODO: Confirm if marker title/snippet needs updating.
                        marker.setPosition(location);
                    }
            }

            /**
             * Removes the marker from its GoogleMap instance
             * @param dataSnapshot  The removed data
             */
            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                    Log.d(TAG, "Location for '" + key + "' was removed.");

                    Marker marker = mNamedMarkers.get(key);
                    if (marker != null)
                        marker.remove()
            }

            /**
             * Ignored.
             * @param dataSnapshot  The moved data
             * @param previousChildName  The key of the previous child event
             */
            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
                    // Unused
                    Log.d(TAG, "Priority for '" + dataSnapshot.getKey() "' was changed.");
            }

            /**
             * Error handler when listener is canceled.
             * @param databaseError  The error object
             */
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "markerUpdateListener:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Failed to load location markers.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
            // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    /**
     * Waits for the map to be ready then loads markers from the database.
     * @param googleMap  The GoogleMap instance
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            mMap = googleMap;

            database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            userLocationsRef = database.getReference("user");

            userLocationsRef.addChildEventListener(markerUpdateListener);



            // later when the activity becomes inactive.
            // userLocationsRef.removeEventListener(markerUpdateListener)
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves the marker data for the given key.
     * @param key  The ID of the marker
     * @return A MarkerOptions instance containing this marker's infoormation
     */
    private MarkerOptions getMarkerOptions(String key) {
        // TODO: Read data from database for the given marker (e.g. Name, Driver, Vehicle type)
        return new MarkerOptions().title('Location placeholder').snippet('Update this with marker information');
    } 
}
```

Comment: that issue is tire me i hope your code working thanks for your effort <33

Comment: sam     Map<String, Marker> mNamedMarkers = new HashMap<String,Marker>();

Comment: i fixed map and make it Hashmap instead

Comment: Glad to hear it judging I haven't touched Java/Android in years.

Comment: god bless you thanks i am try about 3 days without result and you saved me

Comment: iam not know what should i tell you but  i love you <33

Comment: I tried this but , marker not updating to new Location . Please look at my code: 
 https://github.com/muankit/new/blob/master/TrackActivity.java

Comment: After skimming through the linked code, the only immediate issue I see is the use of "lng" on [Line 40](https://github.com/muankit/new/blob/6ac89c42128b7a1cb07ce1dc54b80a78bdd17050/TrackActivity.java#L40) and "lang" on [Line 75](https://github.com/muankit/new/blob/6ac89c42128b7a1cb07ce1dc54b80a78bdd17050/TrackActivity.java#L75)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

And you must implement OnMapReadyCallback

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

}
```

And mMap make private or public variable.

Before calling for loop method

Insert follow code

```
mMap.clear();
```

You're using the wrong way for addValueEventListener.

You can submit addValueEventlistener in onCreate Method, And also need check null before call.

In OnMapReadyCallback method only do bind mMap variable.

Comment: i try it now and tell you the output thanks my brother <3

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker.remove()' on a null object reference

Comment: first check if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) and then call mCurrLocationMarker.clear()

Comment: You can call before for loop.

Comment: @mirzak mCurrLocationMarker.remove ? i cant found mCurrLocationMarker.clear()

Comment: And no way for change position without add marker in Google. In your case  mMap.clear();

Comment: hhhhhh i use mMap.clear before for loop as you say and its working perfectly :''D thanks my friend @Akio Alex

Comment: let me ask you this is a good method it is clear all markers every time is called

Comment: what you think about using it in app

Comment: if i have 100 marker and one is changing the 100 marker are clear and re add to change the position of 1 marker only

Comment: My thought is no other way for update google map marker.

Comment: @AkioAlex but why i dont notice clear other marker when i run app

Comment: i dont notice other marker readded thats good but i dont understand it

Comment: can you explain what is happen exactly in mMap.clear

Comment: In clear method remove all marker on google map markers. So I don't know what happen in method. But there is no other way for update in Google map. If you don't like this, find other library.

Comment: okay very thanks the code is run and i should give you accept answer thanksss <3333

Comment: You can update the previous marker location using `mCurrLocationMarker.setPosition(new LatLng(37.7750,122.4183));` rather than delete the previous marker (make sure to check if `mCurrLocationMarker` is null). [(docs)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html#setPosition(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng))

Comment: @sam  i read you comment but i cant understand it and turn it to code

Comment: I tried this but , marker not updating to new Location . Please look at my code: https://github.com/muankit/new/blob/master/TrackActivity.java

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look for complete tracking of marker, animate and move like uber, with the below Kotlin code :

**Initially add your firebase listener**

```
mFirebaseRef?.child(mDriverId)!!.addChildEventListener(listener);
```

**Define your firebase listener**

```
 var listener = object : ChildEventListener {
    override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
        Log.e("onCancelled", " " + p0.message)
    }

    override fun onChildMoved(p0: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {
        Log.e("onChildMoved", " " + p0.key)
    }

    override fun onChildChanged(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {
        Log.e("onChildChanged", " " + dataSnapshot.key)

      //Write your database reference login for getting Lat Lng

        if (dataSnapshot.key.equals("l")) {
            val latLatLng = dataSnapshot.value as ArrayList<Any>?
            if (latLatLng!!.size == 2) {
                displayLocation(latLatLng) 
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onChildAdded(p0: DataSnapshot, p1: String?) {
        Log.e("onChildAdded", " " + p0.key)
    }

    override fun onChildRemoved(p0: DataSnapshot) {
        Log.e("onChildRemoved", " " + p0.key)
    }
}
```

**Add and update marker with starting zoom for First time**

```
private fun displayLocation(latLatLng: ArrayList<Any>) {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
                REQUEST_LOCATION)
    } else {
        mLastLocation = Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
        mLastLocation!!.latitude = latLatLng[0] as Double;
        mLastLocation!!.longitude = latLatLng[1] as Double;
        val latitude = latLatLng[0]!!
        val longitude = latLatLng[1]!!

        addMarker(mMap, latitude as Double, longitude as Double)

        if (isFirstTime) {
            isFirstTime = false
            try {

                var pickUPLatLng: LatLng = LatLng(pick_lat.toDouble(), pick_long.toDouble())
                var deliveryLatLng: LatLng = LatLng(drop_lat.toDouble(), drop_long.toDouble())

                var latLngBounds: LatLngBounds = LatLngBounds.Builder()
                        .include(pickUPLatLng)
                        .include(deliveryLatLng)
                        .include(LatLng(latitude as Double, longitude as Double))
                        .build()
                lstLatLngRoute.clear()
                try {
                    mLastLocation = Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
                    mLastLocation!!.longitude = longitude as Double
                    mLastLocation!!.latitude = latitude as Double
                    lstLatLngRoute.add(LatLng(mLastLocation!!.latitude, mLastLocation!!.longitude))
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
                lstLatLngRoute.add(pickUPLatLng)
                lstLatLngRoute.add(deliveryLatLng)
                zoomRoute(mMap!!, lstLatLngRoute)
                //mMap!!.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(latLngBounds, 250))
                //mMap!!.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LatLng(latitude as Double, longitude as Double), 14f))
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**Now add marker if not added on Google Map already or use the previous once**

```
private var markerCount: Int = 0
private var marker: Marker? = null;
private var mLastLocation: Location? = null

fun addMarker(googleMap: GoogleMap?, lat: Double, lon: Double) {

    if (markerCount == 1) {

        try {
            try {
                animateMarker(marker!!, LatLng(mLastLocation!!.latitude, mLastLocation!!.longitude))
             } catch (e: Exception) {
            }

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

    } else if (markerCount == 0) {

        var pickUpBmp: Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.carbike)
        mMap = googleMap
        val latlong = LatLng(lat, lon)
        marker = mMap!!.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(LatLng(lat, lon))
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(pickUpBmp))
                .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
                .flat(false))
        mMap!!.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlong, MAP_ZOOM_LEVEL))

        markerCount = 1

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return
        }
    }
}
```

**And at the last  just animate the marker with the below method :**

```
fun animateMarker( marker: Marker,toPosition: LatLng) {
    val handler = Handler()
    val start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis()
    val proj = mMap!!.getProjection()
    val startPoint = proj.toScreenLocation(marker.getPosition())
    val startLatLng = proj.fromScreenLocation(startPoint)
    val duration: Long = 3000

    val interpolator = LinearInterpolator()

    handler.post(object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            val elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start
            val t = interpolator.getInterpolation(elapsed.toFloat() / duration)
            val lng = t * toPosition.longitude + (1 - t) * startLatLng.longitude
            val lat = t * toPosition.latitude + (1 - t) * startLatLng.latitude
            marker.position = LatLng(lat, lng)
            marker.rotation = (getBearingBetweenTwoPoints1(startLatLng, toPosition).toString().toFloat())

            runOnUiThread(Runnable {
                mMap!!.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                        .newCameraPosition(CameraPosition.Builder()
                                .target(toPosition)
                                .zoom(MAP_ZOOM_LEVEL)
                                .build()))
            })

            if (t < 1.0) {
                handler.postDelayed(this, 16)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

**Use below methods for bearing or head calculate of marker**

```
 private fun getBearingBetweenTwoPoints1(latLng1: LatLng, latLng2: LatLng): Double {

    val lat1 = degreesToRadians(latLng1.latitude)
    val long1 = degreesToRadians(latLng1.longitude)
    val lat2 = degreesToRadians(latLng2.latitude)
    val long2 = degreesToRadians(latLng2.longitude)

    val dLon = long2 - long1
    val y = Math.sin(dLon) * Math.cos(lat2)
    val x = Math.cos(lat1) * Math.sin(lat2) - (Math.sin(lat1)
            * Math.cos(lat2) * Math.cos(dLon))

    val radiansBearing = Math.atan2(y, x)
    return radiansToDegrees(radiansBearing)
}

private fun degreesToRadians(degrees: Double): Double {
    return degrees * Math.PI / 180.0
}

private fun radiansToDegrees(radians: Double): Double {
    return radians * 180.0 / Math.PI
}
```

I hope this will help you, If you are familiar with Kotlin :)

@mohamedgaber No need to be confused, just update your listener like this and it will work for number of childrens(Markers) not for single marker(Be sure your markers are different). Just convert this listener in Koltin and use other code same given by me, I promise it will work very smooth like Uber.

```
 myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

            Double lang = ds.child("lang").getValue(Double.class);
            Double lat = ds.child("lat").getValue(Double.class);
            save = new model(lat, lang);
            ll = new LatLng(save.getLat(), save.getLang());

            displayLocation(ll) 

       }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: thanks thanks i will convert it into java code and try it

Comment: @mohamedgaber , Yes please and let me know if you still face any issue.

Comment: my friend i try the other answer in this post its say mMap.clear before                     for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren())  its working but it is the right method or not what your opinion in it

Comment: @mohamedgaber I would avoid using mMap.clear() as it will remove each marker from the map when multiple are present. It is unclear whether you have multiple markers on the map at a time for different users or for the same user. The code provided here by Hemendra, will update the location of a **single** marker with the most recent lat/lng values while also using the more efficient [`child_*` event listeners](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#child-events) to listen for updates instead of listening to the entire user's data.

Comment: i know but problem iam very poor in kotlin i am trying to run code but this very hard for me

Comment: val latLatLng = dataSnapshot.value as ArrayList<Any>?
            if (latLatLng!!.size == 2) {
                displayLocation(latLatLng) 
            }
not understand it

Comment: i am still trying but without any result iam poor at kotlin

Comment: @mohamedgaber just updated my answer at bottom, Check it once.

Comment: displayLocation have many errors i cant understand it and resolve it

Comment: i notice GPS_PROVIDER but i dont need it

Comment: i only seek update the lat and lang by read lat and lang from firebase

Comment: please if you have solve of my problem help me with that

Comment: Its my requirement, if you do not need it, you can remove the condition

Answer (score 0):

```
    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
            dbref.addSnapshotListener(Mapsimport1.this, new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                    if (e != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(Mapsimport1.this, "Error while loading!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
                        return;
                    }

                    if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                        String acmilan = documentSnapshot.getString(marker.getTitle());
                                Log.d("acmilan**",acmilan);
                        marker.setSnippet(acmilan);                        }
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
```