# Change marker position based on Realtime lat and lang Firebase without (Mmap.clear) or if (marker != null)

Tags: java, android, google-maps, firebase-realtime-database

i seek to update location of marker by change value of lat&lang in Firebase Realtime but i still can't do that:

I tried :
1-

```
Marker marker ;
if(marker==null){
  addmarker
}
else {
  setPosition
}
```

the problem is : I have many markers so `marker!=null` so `addMarker` method is stopped forever

2-

```
mMap.clear
```

the problem is : if i have in my app 1000 markers and 1 is changed its position 999 has effect

```
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                Double lang = ds.child("lang").getValue(Double.class);
                Double lat = ds.child("lat").getValue(Double.class);
                save = new model(lat, lang);
                ll = new LatLng(save.getLat(), save.getLang());




            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

WHAT i want is when change realtime database values marker is change its position also

Comment: you were asking same question right https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55570188/change-markers-position-base-on-realtime-firebase-lat-and-lang-values/55570409#55570409

Comment: yea am asked this and this

Comment: Please delete this question and instead update your other question with this information.