# How to move marker along Polyline in Real-time using values from firebase

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have a car marker that is getting GPS data from firebase. The problem is the location updates is not always on the road. It will sometimes deviate from the road like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSyt8.png).
I want the car marker to be on the road all the time like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGyhA.jpg).

Code for retrieving GPS location from firebase

```
DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
final DatabaseReference AV = root.child("ID:1");
final DatabaseReference dest = AV.child("Destination");
final DatabaseReference pick = AV.child("Pick up");
final DatabaseReference Carlocation = AV.child("Current Location");                   


Carlocation.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
       if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("Latitude")) {
          Double lat = dataSnapshot.child("Latitude").getValue(Double.class);
          Double lon = dataSnapshot.child("Longitude").getValue(Double.class);
          Driverlocation = new LatLng(lat, lon);
          Car_marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                  .position(Driverlocation)
                  .icon(bitmapDescriptorFromVector(MainActivity.this, R.drawable.ic_car)));

                        }}

     @Override
     public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
         throw databaseError.toException(); 
     }
   });
```

I am using this library to draw the polyline between two points https://github.com/jd-alexander/google-directions-android

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55570188/change-markers-position-base-on-realtime-firebase-lat-and-lang-values/55570409#55570409  check this link here 
 i answered

Comment: @MurugananthamS Hi, my marker is already able to update its current location and display on the map successfully. However, I want the marker to stay and move along the road/polyline all the time like how Gojek app does.

Comment: if you are getting a correct latlon it will move the exact path, if suppose you are deviating from  polyline path the marker will change its position, or else again you have to draw the new polyline

Comment: @MurugananthamS How to stop marker from deviating from route/path? I use Fused location for the GPS, is it not accurate enough?

Comment: https://github.com/yayaa/LocationManager use this library it will give exact location i have used this library only

Comment: fused location is accurate enough. try using long distance path and moving your driver location source physically. And please try to use an animation to move the vehicle icon.

Comment: yes fused location is enough to get accurate location, if we are using bearing value above mentioned answer it will move smoothly , I have used my project above code only

Comment: @MurugananthamS hey I have tried this library. I am getting the same result as Fused location. The marker will still deviate from route/path.

Comment: @Sajith what is using long-distance path? I have tried moving the driver location source physically using mobile data for GPS and I did use animation for moving the vehicle icon using this library https://gist.github.com/broady/6314689 But my vehicle icon still deviate from path/route

Comment: @Silver please select a route with long distance. that means may be 5 KM for testing only. And try with following the route with actual device.

Comment: @Silver have you round up the decimal points of latitude and longitude?

Comment: @Sajith Hey, I have not rounded up the decimal point. Do I need to round them up? If need, to how many decimal points?

Comment: @Silver no you dont want to do it. if it rounds up, the accuracy of the location decrease. I just ask,  as you said location is not accurate .